# Android error when add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Tags: android, firebase

I am working with Firebase in my project. when I add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'in gradle it goes wrong. logcat says :Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
Missing api_key/current_key object. I searched a lot but no luck. How to remove this error. please help.

Comment: did you add the `google-services.json` file to your project? Described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#manually_add_firebase) in step 4?

Comment: just re download your google-services.json file & update it in your app folder

Comment: @EarlOfEgo I did it properly according to doc

Comment: do you change the application id? Make sure you have an app for all application ids, like `com.company.yourapp` + `com.company.yourapp.debug`

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your app with firebase and obtained the api_key/current_key. After doing so u will get an google-services.json file, paste this file to path Project-->app (as shown in image).
[image: refer image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have google-services.json file in your root directory.
1. Go to your firebase console
2. open your project and download the google-services.json file **again** from settings.
3. place this newly downloaded json file in the root directory.
4. Check whether json file contains api key field.